# How do you correctly handle errors using PT Contact Form when submitting via AJAX?

Tags: form, ajax, plugin-contactform

I'm trying out AJAX submission for the PT Contact Form for the first time. I've managed to get errors appearing on the frontend, but I don't feel like I'm doing it the right way. It also doens't integrated at all with the `{% macro errorList(errors) %}` code that comes with the form. This is my form JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#ajax-form').submit(function(ev) {
        // Prevent the form from actually submitting
        ev.preventDefault();

        // Get the post data
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        // Send it to the server
        $.post('/', data, function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                $('#thanks').fadeIn();
            } else {
                // response.error will be an object containing any validation errors that occurred, indexed by field name
                // e.g. response.error.fromName => ['From Name is required']
                if (response.error.fromName) {$('ul.errors').append('<li>'+response.error.fromName+'</li>');}
                if (response.error.fromEmail) {$('ul.errors').append('<li>'+response.error.fromEmail+'</li>');}
                if (response.error.subject) {$('ul.errors').append('<li>'+response.error.subject+'</li>');}
                if (response.error.message) {$('ul.errors').append('<li>'+response.error.message+'</li>');}
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Form code:

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
{% if errors %}
<ul class="errors">
    {% for error in errors %}
    <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import errorList %}

<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="ajax-form">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/contact">

    <label for="fromName">Name *</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="fromName" type="text" name="fromName" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromName }}{% endif %}">
    {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromName')) }}

    <label for="fromEmail">Email *</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="fromEmail" type="text" name="fromEmail" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromEmail }}{% endif %}">
    {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="subject" type="text" name="subject" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.subject }}{% endif %}">
    {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('subject')) }}

    <label for="message">Message *</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" cols="40" id="message" name="message">{% if message is defined %}{{ message.message }}{% endif %}</textarea>
    {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('message')) }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<ul class="my-errors"></ul>
```

I've had to put a blank `<ul class="my-errors"></ul>` under my form, as the `.error` ul that comes with the contact form doesn't appear. Where am I going wrong?

Desired result: I get exactly the same error handling as I would if I wasn't submitting via AJAX - i.e., the error messages relating to specific fields appear under those fields in the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the error messages to be displayed identical to P&T's template/macro default, this should do the trick:

```
$(function(){
    $('#ajax-form').submit( function(ev) {

        // Prevent the form from actually submitting
        ev.preventDefault();

        // Remove any existing error messages from previous attempts
        $(this).find( '.errors' ).remove();

        // Get the post data
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        // Send it to the server
        $.post('/', data, function(response) {

            if (response.success) {

                // All good!
                $('#thanks').fadeIn();

            } else {

                // Loop through the errors and append to relevant fields
                for ( var fieldId in response.error ) {

                    // Create the <ul>
                    var $errors = $( '<ul class="errors" />' );

                    // Wrap the error messages in <li> tags
                    var messages = $.map(response.error[fieldId], function(message){
                        return '<li>' + message + '</li>';
                    });

                    // Append the error messages to the ul
                    $errors.append( messages.join( '' ) );

                    // Select the input element and append the .errors <ul> after it.
                    $('#'+fieldId).after($errors);

                }

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Just to be clear though, the PT Contact Form template doesn't force you to display your error messages in any given way; both the contact form template as a whole, and specifically how error messages are displayed (both the template macro for non-Ajax requests and the stuff in the `response.error` object) is obviously totally up to you.