# Template for submit via ajax to Guest Entries plugin

Tags: ajax

I am a bit mystified by how to utilize templates for Guest entries plugin working fine for normal post saving custom fields.

When I use ajax to submit I get an XHR 200 response but an HTML response - no JSON. Ideally I don't want to redirect to another page but just manipulate the DOM and pass some variables into the page form JSON returned on success.

I have read and reread every ajax post but still can't get a pure JSON response

Is it necessary to utilize some kind of detection within the template for Craft ajax?

Just when I thought i had ajax understood...

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//validation rules
$("form#brick").validate({
    ignore: ":hidden",
    rules: {
        "fields[firstName]": {
            required: true,
        },
        "fields[lastName]": {
            required: true
        },
        "fields[email]": {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "fields[email]": "Email is required"
    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {
        // Prevent default posting of form
        event.preventDefault();

        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax('/', data, function(response) {
            if (response.success) {

                console.log(response);
                $('#thanks').fadeIn();
                $('#brick').fadeOut();
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                // response.error will be an object containing any validation errors that occurred, indexed by field name
                // e.g. response.error.fromName => ['From Name is required']
                alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: What is the HTML that is being received? Are entries getting saved when you perform this AJAX request?

Comment: There's a bug in your JavaScript – `function (form) {...` should be `function (event) {...`; the bug means you're not properly preventing the form's default submission. Not sure if that's the root cause of your issue, though.

Comment: Updated JS above
Works fine.
The html in the ajax response is the core index.html template being loaded....
So confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with your JavaScript that I expect is the cause of your issue.

From your code I'm assuming you're using [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate the form before submission. Your first issue is the line

```
event.preventDefault();
```

within the `submitHandler()` method – jQuery Validate will actually prevent the default form submission for you, so this line is redundant. Also, there is no variable called `event`, so that's going to cause trouble.

The second issue is that you're using the wrong syntax for the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method. Considering your current code, I believe you want to use the [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method instead.

Finally, you're serializing the wrong object – `$(this).serialize()` should actually read `$(form).serialize()`.

With the above issues fixed, your code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form#brick').validate({

        ignore: ":hidden",

        rules: {
            "fields[firstName]": {
                required: true,
            },
            "fields[lastName]": {
                required: true
            },
            "fields[email]": {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            "fields[email]": "Email is required"
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {

            var data = $(form).serialize();

            $.post('/', data, function (response) {
                if (response && response.success) {
                    $('#thanks').fadeIn();
                    $('#brick').fadeOut();
                } else {
                    alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
                }
            });

        }

    });

});
```

Finally, for some pointers on how you could handle errors within the `response` payload, see [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8722/how-do-you-correctly-handle-errors-using-pt-contact-form-when-submitting-via-aja?rq=1).